# How can I validate a password before hashing it in MongoDB User Schema using RegEx validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, mongodb, schema

I am currently working on a hotel booking site. Here is the [link](https://github.com/HF-exp-2-pi-i-x/MERN-hotel-booking-project.git).

I am trying to validate my password for user login. In the User schema, I have added validator (which validates the password by Regex).

```
//User.js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
password:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate:{
      validator: function(p){
        const re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/g;
        return re.test(p);
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid password`
    },
  }
...
})
```

While in the register function, I have already hashed my password and saved in user document. And the result of hash must satisfy my validation(at least 1 capital letter, 1 small letter, 1 number, 8 characters).

```
//auth.js
export const register = async (req,res,next)=>{
  try{

    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password,salt);

    const newUser = new User({
      ...req.body,
      password: hash
    });
    
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).send("User has been created.");
  }catch(err){
    next(err);
  }
}
```

So I want to ask if there is a way to validate my password before hashing?

I have tried to do something like

```js
 const user = new User();
     user.password = req.body.password;
     if(user.validateSync()){
      next(user.validateSync());
     }
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate function that performs the password validation on server side, and then you can use this in your `auth.js` file.

```js
const validatePassword = (password) => {
  const re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/g;
  return re.test(password);
};
```

```js
export const register = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { password } = req.body;

    if (!validatePassword(password)) {
      throw new Error('Invalid password');
    }

    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

    const newUser = new User({
      ...req.body,
      password: hash,
    });

    await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).send("User has been created.");
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```